# Could feature interaction constrains be enforced in h2o.xgboost in R

Tags: r, xgboost, h2o, interaction

I am building xgboost models using h2o.xgboost() in R.

Could feature interaction constraints (as described in https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/feature_interaction_constraint.html) be used? I did not find anything related in the official documentation of h2o.xgboost.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This feature is being added in upcoming release. See this [Jira](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-7774) for the status.